# How to get the background image of canvas after loading with loadFromJSON fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs

When I load json string of canvas with background image and objects. I can not get the background image. when I console the data i can not see the background image there.
How can I bind the background image in JSON.stringify() function when saving the canvas in database?

Comment: it should work. Can you post a code of what you tried so far?

Comment: I have got a solution for this. Actually I was getting background image before its loading properly.

Comment: so please delete this question instead of leaving un answered or uncomplete.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it is important when to call `canvas.toJSON()`.

It is also very important to note this: you might see the background image property in your json *string*, but the image would not be saved properly at the time of `canvas.toJSON()` call. So as a result when you call `loadFromJSON`, every object is loaded into canvas except the background image.

Also, make sure you always use the latest fabricjs version.